# css3 transition delay of specific attribute

Tags: css, css-transitions

at the moment I am styling a textbox by changing its background-color and font color on hover :

```
transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
```

I would now like to change the color after the background color by using transition-delay. The problem is that transition delay does not take the PROPERTY (i.e. color) that I would like to delay. Is there any way to delay specific attributes only?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Transition Delay is property specific.

For instance

```
transition: background-color 1s linear 2s, color 1s;
transition: property name | duration | timing function | delay
```

When using shorthand, it seems as though you need to specify the timing function as well.

([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition))

Comment: Just for completion, the default timing function is ease (ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp). And no, it doesn't seem to be necessary to indicate it, at least with modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

```
li {
  transition-duration: 0.4s, 0.4s, 0.4s, 0.4s, 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s, 0s, 0s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, visibility, color, background-color;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s, 0s, 0s;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s, 0.1s, 0.1s, 0s, 0s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The good news is that you can configure transition parameters i.e. `transition-delay`, `transition-duration` etc. for a specific css property. The sad news is that you cannot specify different parameters for different css properties on the same element. For example, this won't work:

```
.elem {
    transition: background-color 2s 0.5s ease; // want background-color to transition differently
    transition: opacity 3s 1.5s ease;          //this unfortunately overrides the previous line
}
```

In that case I would suggest using animations with `@keyframes`. The code is a bit more elaborate but then you can apply timing, duration, etc. more liberally.

Comment: You can: `transition: background-color 2s 0.5s ease, opacity 3s 1.5s ease;`